# 50歳以上かつ30歳以下が表示できない。

Tags: mysql, sql

## 実行したい事

最年長が50歳以上かつ最年少が30歳以下の国を表示させてください。

[image: Image from Gyazo]

## 現状

返り値が空になってしまい、MAX、MINが写真通りに表示されません。
分かる方居ましたらお願い致します。
[image: Image from Gyazo]

## 現状コード

```sql
SELECT 
age 
FROM
celebrities
WHERE 
age >= 50 AND age <= 30;
```

celebrities テーブル

```
-- テーブルのデータのダンプ `celebrities`
--

INSERT INTO `celebrities` (`id`, `name`, `country_code`, `birth`, `age`, `occupation`) VALUES
(1, 'Emma Charlotte Duerre Watson', 'FRA', '1990-04-15 00:00:00', 31, 'actor'),
(2, 'Johnny Depp', 'USA', '1963-06-09 00:00:00', 58, 'actor'),
(3, 'Jim Carrey', 'USA', '1962-01-17 00:00:00', 59, 'actor'),
(4, 'Daniel Radcliffe', 'GBR', '1989-07-23 00:00:00', 32, 'actor'),
(5, 'Morgan Freeman', 'USA', '1937-06-01 00:00:00', 84, 'actor'),
(6, 'Hugh Jackman', 'AUS', '1968-10-12 00:00:00', 53, 'actor'),
(7, 'Natalie Portman', '', '1981-06-09 00:00:00', 40, 'actor'),
(8, 'Pierce Brosnan', 'FRA', '1960-10-15 00:00:00', 61, 'actor'),
(9, 'Sean Connery', 'PER', '1980-05-05 00:00:00', 41, 'singer'),
(10, 'Dwayne Johnson', 'USA', '1978-12-15 00:00:00', 43, 'fighter'),
(11, 'Jackie Chan', 'USA', '1992-04-15 00:00:00', 29, 'fighter'),
(12, 'Adam Sandler', 'FRA', '1976-02-05 00:00:00', 45, 'singer'),
(13, 'Scarlett Johansson', 'AUT', '1966-01-10 00:00:00', 55, 'model'),
(14, 'Heath Ledger', 'USA', '1971-10-15 00:00:00', 50, 'actor'),
(15, 'Edward Norton', 'GBR', '1988-03-12 00:00:00', 33, 'actor'),
(16, 'Keira Knightley', 'GBR', '1980-11-10 00:00:00', 41, 'model'),
(17, 'Bradley Cooper', 'USA', '1979-08-01 00:00:00', 42, 'fighter'),
(18, 'Will Ferrell', 'USA', '1966-01-15 00:00:00', 53, 'comedian'),
(19, 'Julia Roberts', 'GRC', '1964-09-01 00:00:00', 55, 'actor'),
(20, 'Daniel Craig', 'USA', '1977-12-09 00:00:00', 44, 'actor'),
(21, 'Ian McKellen', '', '1998-04-15 00:00:00', 23, 'singer'),
(22, 'Samuel L. Jackson', 'USA', '1960-04-09 00:00:00', 61, 'actor'),
(23, 'Ben Stiller', 'BRA', '1964-10-15 00:00:00', 57, 'actor'),
(24, 'Tommy Lee Jones', '', '1970-09-05 00:00:00', 51, 'comedian'),
(25, 'Antonio Banderas', 'USA', '1958-10-05 00:00:00', 63, 'actor'),
(26, 'Denzel Washington', 'USA', '1990-10-25 00:00:00', 31, 'model'),
(27, 'Steve Carell', 'USA', '1991-02-14 00:00:00', 30, 'actor'),
(28, 'Shia LaBeouf', 'CHL', '1991-10-05 00:00:00', 30, 'actor'),
(29, 'Megan Fox', 'GRC', '1992-09-23 00:00:00', 29, 'actor'),
(30, 'James Franco', 'USA', '1955-04-15 00:00:00', 66, 'actor'),
(31, 'Mel Gibson', 'COL', '1967-03-08 00:00:00', 54, 'singer'),
(32, 'Vin Diesel', 'USA', '1982-11-15 00:00:00', 39, 'singer'),
(33, 'Tim Allen', 'ISL', '1962-02-10 00:00:00', 59, 'actor'),
(34, 'Kevin Spacey', 'USA', '1990-04-15 00:00:00', 31, 'actor'),
(35, 'Jason Biggs', 'USA', '1979-03-25 00:00:00', 42, 'actor'),
(36, 'Seann William Scott', 'USA', '1957-02-22 00:00:00', 64, 'actor'),
(37, 'Jean-Claude Van Damme', 'USA', '1997-01-10 00:00:00', 24, 'model'),
(38, 'Zach Galifianakis', 'USA', '1969-04-22 00:00:00', 52, 'actor'),
(39, 'Owen Wilson', 'USA', '1988-06-05 00:00:00', 31, 'actor'),
(40, 'Christian Bale', 'USA', '1977-12-01 00:00:00', 44, 'actor'),
(41, 'Peter Jackson', 'USA', '1994-10-25 00:00:00', 27, 'model'),
(42, 'Sandra Bullock', 'CUA', '1975-07-19 00:00:00', 46, 'actor'),
(43, 'Drew Barrymore', 'USA', '1993-06-05 00:00:00', 28, 'singer'),
(44, 'Macaulay Culkin', 'ESP', '1981-07-22 00:00:00', 40, 'comedian'),
(45, 'Bill Murray', 'USA', '1988-03-09 00:00:00', 33, 'actor'),
(46, 'Sigourney Weaver', 'FIN', '1954-12-10 00:00:00', 67, 'actor'),
(47, 'Jake Gyllenhaal', '', '1990-05-05 00:00:00', 31, 'model'),
(48, 'Jason Statham', 'USA', '1986-06-08 00:00:00', 35, 'actor');
```

Comment: 問題文も重要なので画像でなくテキストで記述するべきです。画像ではQ&Aの蓄積に貢献せず、当サイトの趣旨に反します。

Comment: 仰る通りですね。失礼致しました。テキストに編集しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題文に関連する教材において、`group by`によるグループ化について`min`や`max`などの集計関数の値を条件式とする場合は`where`句ではなく`having`句を使う旨が書かれていると思います。

おそらく下記のSQLが回答例になります。
参考にしながら教材を確認してみてください。

※そして他の人の役に立つように質問文を書き直していただけると嬉しいです。

```
select   country_code, max(ce.age), min(ce.age)
from     celebrities ce
group by country_code
having   max(ce.age) >= 50
and      min(ce.age) <= 30
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6gQVxSAHDHefTygQm5kq7P/0)